# How to add additional statsd mapping config in airflow helm chart

Tags: airflow, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, statsd

In standalone statsd-exporter we can add statsd config mapping file (yml) to parameter `--statsd.mapping-config` ([reference](https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/statsd-exporter)), so we can mapping metrics that send from airflow. But when I use airflow helm chart, I confuse how we can add additional config mapping in default statsd-exporter from airflow chart? Thank you

Actually, I found parameter `extraMappings=[]` in values.yml that have possibilities to add mapping, but I still don't know how to use it
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add mappings simply by adding an array in your custom `my_values.yml`:

```yaml
extraMappings:
  - match: "test.*.*.counter"
    name: "..."
    labels:
      provider: "..."
  - match: "test2.*.*.counter"
    name: "$..."
    labels:
      provider: "..."
```

And then using your file:

`helm install -f my_values.yaml CHART_SPECIFICATION`

You can see sime examples of mapping in the reference you mentioned.

Comment: Wow, thanks @JarekPotiuk its works!!! But, I'm still curious, can we include the mapping in the different files instead of writing down all of the extra mappings inside values.yml?